# wrapfig continues to wrap itemize below

Tags: latex

I am using a wrapfigi environment one paragraph above an itemize environment, but it looks like the wrapping continues down the entire list even if it is separated by a paragraph. I have also tried to use the optional number of lines parameter but it doesnt seem to fix it. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNMaW.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwIyA.png)

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{l}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width = .9\linewidth]{Images/NodeDegree.png}

    \captionsetup{width = .9\linewidth, labelfont = bf, font = small}
    \caption{A graph representing the node degree distribution of the network. x-axis is the degree of each node, and the y-axis is the number of nodes with each degree. R-value = 0.865, function = $P(k) = 64.06 \cdot k^{-1.43}$.}
    \label{fig: nodeDegree}
\end{wrapfigure}

Comparative analysis between our, the master, and the random network was performed to provide a measure of significance for the nodes in our network and a reference from which to analyze our own metrics.

\begin{itemize}
    \item Scale-free \textbf{(power-law figure)}

Scale-freeness is a result from the power law of the node degree distribution. A result of a few nodes (the hubs) having large degrees (large number of connections) compared to the rest. The scale-freeness provides robustness against random failures but is vulnerable to targeted attacks

    \item Node degree distribution

A measure of how many connections a node has. Nodes with high degree (many connections) usually form hubs.
```

I tried both with and without the optional parameter, as well as different values for this. I also tried with both float and static l/L parameter, but none of these changed the outcome.